# x-ms-webview is not displaying properly in windows phone 8.1 javascript app

Tags: javascript, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a wp8.1 app in javascript. The x-ms-webview is being displayed in a very small size.
Screenshot:
https://flic.kr/p/oi2WNm

**default.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Miley_Cyrus_Tweets.WindowsPhone</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <!-- At runtime, ui-themed.css resolves to ui-themed.light.css or ui-themed.dark.css 
    based on the user’s theme setting. This is part of the MRT resource loading functionality. -->
    <link href="/css/ui-themed.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Miley_Cyrus_Tweets.Phone references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="phone">
    <center>
        <br /><br />
        <x-ms-webview id="webview" src="ms-appx-web:///page.html" width="400" height="600"></x-ms-webview>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**default.css**

```
body {
background-color: #ffffff;

}
```

Here's what I've tried to make it bigger:

1. Increasing width and height values of x-ms-webview in default.html
2. Using zoom: 200%; for body in default.css

In both cases, the x-ms-webview became larger but also shifted toward right.

So, my question is:
What do I need to do to make it bigger while keeping it center-aligned?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps these code will help you.

it comes from cordova inappbrowser.

```js
if (!browserWrap) {
  browserWrap = document.createElement("div");
  browserWrap.style.position = "absolute";
  browserWrap.style.borderWidth = "0";
  browserWrap.style.width = "100%";
  browserWrap.style.height = "100%";
  browserWrap.style.borderStyle = "solid";
  browserWrap.style.borderColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.25)";
  browserWrap.style.zIndex = 100000;

  document.body.appendChild(browserWrap);
}


popup = document.createElement(isWebViewAvailable ? "x-ms-webview" : "iframe");
popup.style.borderWidth = "0";
popup.style.width = "100%";
popup.style.height = "100%";
popup.src = strUrl;
browserWrap.appendChild(popup);
```